# MongooseJS near not working with Keystone Location field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I have a model with an address field that is type Location (KeystoneJS address + geo coordinates). As I understand it, the geo coordinates in this field are indexed as 2dSphere.

However, if I try to query with the MongooseJS near function it returns an error:

```
var point = [3.2642048999999815241,50.830799100000090124];
Challenge.model.find(
    {status: 1}
)
.where('location')
.near({
    center: point, 
    maxDistance: maxDistance, 
    spherical: true
})
.populate('waypoints')
.exec(function(err, challenges) {
    if(err) return res.apiError('1000', Errors['1000']);
    return res.apiResponse({
        challenges: challenges
    });
});
```

returns:

> MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { status: 1, location: { $nearSphere: [ 3.264204899999982, 50.83079910000009 ], $maxDistance: 1000 } }

I don't understand why it throws an error for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in MongooseJS. If you use MongoDB query notation it works:

```
Challenge.model.find(
        {
         status: 1, 
         "location.geo": {$near: { $geometry:{ type: "Point", coordinates: location }, $maxDistance: maxDistance}}},
         "-__v -updatedOn -createdOn -slug")
.populate('waypoints')
.exec(function(err, challenges) {
    if(err) return res.apiError('1000', Errors['1000']);
    return res.apiResponse({
        challenges: challenges
    });
});
```